# Partition errors

Tags: mount, partitioning

I am new to Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu and I think I have jumbled up the partitions. I wanted to create 3 logical Disks of 250Gb where Ubuntu will be installed and two other disks for files and other stuff.

But after installation I am able to see the disks as folders in root directory and unable to write anything to those folder, (wrong mount points maybe :( ).
Here are the mount points I gave during installation:

- First Disk:  `mount point: \`
- Second Disk: `mount Point: \drive1`
- Third Disk:  `mount point: \drive2`

When I tried to reformat using g`nome-disk-utility 3.10.0` I got these errors:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/JyOW86P.png]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/8mOaKAb.png]

Comment: Here are the screenshots of errors
http://i.imgur.com/8mOaKAb.png

http://i.imgur.com/JyOW86P.png

Comment: You cannot modify partitions that are mounted. If you were using gparted you would see little lock icons. You need to use live installer which has gparted or gparted liveCD to modify partitions. I believe Disks is also on live installer, but never have used it to create new partitions, just edit labels or minor things.

Answer (score 1):

First, in Linux the forward slash (`/`) is used as a directory separator, not the backslash (`\`). This *might* be contributing to your problems, but you've probably just transcribed it wrong in your question. I mention it simply to cover the most fundamental thing first. Also, in the Linux world partitions are not referred to as "drives" or "disks"; they're "partitions" or "filesystems," depending on context. The words "drive" and "disk" usually refer to your hardware, so you can't "create... disks."

Second, the sort of error message you're reporting is often caused by rounding issues in the partitioning software. That is, the software might say that Partition A ends at "250MiB," when in fact it ends at 250.25MiB. When you tell it to begin the next partition at 250MiB, it displays an error like what you've shown because 250.00MiB is less than 250.25MiB, and of course it can't comply. There are two solutions:

- Leave a short gap between the partitions -- tell it to start the partition 1MiB *after* the end of the preceding one and 1MiB *before* the beginning of the next one. You may end up with small gaps between your partitions, but at least you'll have partitions.
- Use another partitioning tool -- GNOME Disk Utility has its points, but it's a little less polished and precise than some others. GParted is what I prefer when I want a GUI tool or need to resize partitions; and I use `gdisk` (for GPT) or `fdisk` (for MBR) for precise command-line operations. (Disclaimer: I wrote `gdisk`, so I'm not exactly unbiased.) Both `gdisk` and `fdisk` use sectors as units, so you can place your partitions with precision. (The values may round a bit to comply with certain alignment rules, though.)

Before I end, I want to make two more points:

- I suspect you're approaching your partitioning task with Windows assumptions. Vanishingly few experienced Linux users would create partitions to be mounted as `/drive1` and `/drive2`. The Linux unified directory tree is very well-defined, with directories like `/usr`, `/home`, `/var`, and `/tmp`. Experienced administrators may split one or more of those directories (or various others) off into their own partitions, but it's unclear to me what you hope to accomplish with `/drive1` and `/drive2`. Linux program files will not be stored there (mostly they go in `/usr`) and user files normally reside in `/home`. You can learn more about this by reading up on the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS) on Wikipedia,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) among other places.
- Most modern computers (those sold since mid-2011) use (U)EFI, which works best with GPT, rather than the MBR partitioning scheme you seem to be using. To be sure, most EFIs include the ability to boot in the old BIOS mode, which generally uses MBR, but at this point, IMHO it makes most sense to stick to EFI and GPT with new machines. If your computer is older, of course, it may be BIOS-based, and early EFI implementations were often flaky enough that using them in BIOS mode might make sense. See [this page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootmode.html) for more on identifying your computer's capabilities and the boot mode of your Ubuntu installer.